# To what extent can the Microsoft Hololens be used to detect objects?

Tags: augmented-reality, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I am starting a project that looks into how capable the Hololens is at detecting 3D objects (How small can the object be? What shape does the object have to be?)

For example, if I were to look at a shoe using the Hololens would it be able to capture all the points that on the shoe's surface? I looked into the specs of the Hololens and it says it has "environment understanding cameras", but does that mean they are 3D cameras and how precise can they be?

The reason I ask is that I worked through a tutorial that would allow you to view the mesh of a room scan, and the likes of chairs and tables looked like lumps growing out from the ground, rather than autonomous objects. And if I wanted the hololens to detect a shoe and do something with it, a lump is going to be of no use.

I am new to all sorts of image/3D object detection so any resources to help explain how it works would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

**Per se, Hololens doesn't detect objects.** Its only detects surfaces. Maybe, the Hololens may detect a variance in a surface if its detect a shoe (i.e. you have a single shoe in your floor). But you could not know (a priori) if its variance is made by a show or a *imperfection* in the floor.

In concrete: If you want to detect a shoe, I recommend you to research about object detection from [Vuforia](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Object-Recognition). This is the easiest ways if you want to detect a previously given object.

If you want to go further and detect shoes, tennis and other kind of shoes, I recommend to use any existing lib/framework for AI/Machine Learning and train a neural network with multiples shoes images and pass a photo from the HoloLens camera and process the information returned by the neural network.

Comment: That's fantastic! Thank you so much for your answer.